# ssh-agent on mac shows old identity

Tags: ssh, mac, ssh-agent

I migrated my data from my old mac to a new machine. This copied the .ssh directory, so `ssh-add -L` showed my old identity.

I decided to remove that using `ssh-add -D`, then created a new identity using `ssh-keygen`.

A subsequent `ssh-add -L` shows both my old AND my new identity. Logging out and rebooting don't help, it keeps showing the old identity AND the new one. The only files containing keys I can find are in .ssh (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub), and those correspond to the new identity I generated.

How does the old identity keep being loaded? Is it stored somewhere by Mac OS? Maybe in the keychain? How can I permanently remove it?

Comment: I don't know macOS, but in my Kubuntu `ssh-add -L` (or `ssh-add -l`) shows pathnames of files used. Does your `ssh-add -L` do this? Is there a pathname associated with the old identity? What is it?

Comment: No, `ssh-add -L` just shows the keys. I'm a long time linux user and I've never seen a path in the output of this command..?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using the GPG agent for SSH as well, and the old identity was being cached by GPG. Editing the file ~/.gnupg/sshcontrol, and removing the old identity, fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add -D` only removes the knowledge of identities from the running agent. You'll just need to go into your `~/.ssh` directory and remove the old identity to permanently delete it.

Comment: From the question: "The only files containing keys I can find are in .ssh (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub), and those correspond to the new identity I generated". How is your answer helpful in this situation. Or are you saying the OP missed some files in `~/.ssh` and should look better?